# $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{2n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the Problem from the textbook "Intro to analysis" by Arthur Mattuck

> Prove that $a_k := \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{2n+1}{2n}$ is strictly increasing and not bounded above.

Strict increasing is trivial: $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} > 1$. But I am stuck at showing $a_k$ is not bounded above. If it is bounded above, then it must have a limit, so I think it suffices to show it diverges. But I also don't know how to show it's divergent.

Could anyone give me some hint on this?

Comment: There is a nice trick that $(1+x)(1+y)\ge 1+x+y$. Using this you will get for example that $$a_3=(1+\frac{1}{2})(1+\frac{1}{4})(1+\frac{1}{6})\ge (1+\frac12+\frac14)(1+\frac16) \ge 1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac16$$
Can you complete it from here?

Comment: @Sayan Yes then it is greater than half of the harmonic series, which divergent! Thanks!

Comment: Two useful elementary lemmas: (1). If each $a_n\ge 0. $ Then $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}a_n$ converges iff $\prod_{n\in \Bbb N}(1+a_n)$ converges. (2). If $a_n\in [0,1)$ for each $n. $ Then $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}a_n$ converges iff $\prod_{n\in \Bbb N}(1-a_n)\ne 0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you for your suggestion! Do you have proofs for them? I don't see it immediately that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\prod_{n} (1+a_n)$; and I don't see the second lemma as well.

Comment: (1).If $x\ge 0$ then $0\le \ln (1+x)=\int_1^{1+x}(1/t)dt\le \int_1^{1+x}(1)dt=x.$ So if each $a_n\ge 0$ then $0\le \ln (\,\prod_{j=1}^n(1+a_j)\,)=\sum_{j=1}^n\ln(1+a_n)\le \sum_{j=1}^n a_n.$... (2). If there are only finitely many terms $1-a_n$ with $a_n>1/2 $ then delete those terms, without affecting convergence or non-convergence. Now if $0\le a_n\le 1/2$ then $(1-a_n)^{-1}=1+b_n$ with $a_n\le b_n\le 2a_n,$ so apply Lemma 1 to $\sum_n b_n$ and $\prod_n(1+b_n).$

Comment: There is a simple non-calculus proof of these lemmas in Introduction To Sequences And Series, by Bromwich. (Different editions have slightly differing titles). I had a copy from Dover Press (now Dover Publications), an excellent source of very cheap re-prints of science & math books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a_n)$ is not bounded by above if and only the sequence defined by if$$\log(a_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right),$$
is not bounded by above. Since $$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\sim \frac{1}{2n},$$
this should be rather clear.

Answer (score 3):

It is greater than $b_k=\prod_{n=1}^k\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}$ and $a_kb_k=k+1$ because the products telescope.
So $a_k\gt\sqrt{k+1}$